# Fragment listview not refreshed once backbutton is pressed

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Implementing a CustomListview with OnScroll listener for loading contents from server. On backpress the fragment returns to home fragment in the container. Again loading the same list view, on button click, only last few items are loaded to the list view even when the a new instance of the child fragment is created.

`notifydatasetchanged()` is called for any change in dataset.

Code `onclicklistener` for displaying `fragment`:

```
 card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){                      
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
                        fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Container, new frag()).addToBackStack("card").commit();
}
```

`Asynctask` is used for loading adapter in  `onScroll` method.

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            private int currentVisibleItemCount;
            private int currentScrollState;
            private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
            private int totalItem;
            // private LinearLayout lBelow;


            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                this.isScrollCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
                this.totalItem = totalItemCount;
            }

            private void isScrollCompleted() {
                if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                        && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    // if ( this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                    /** To do code here*/

                    scrollpos = this.totalItem;
                    int lastPos = this.currentFirstVisibleItem + this.currentVisibleItemCount;
                    if (lastPos == scrollpos && !loadingMore) {
                        if (this.totalItem < jsonobjectcount-1) {
                            int index = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                            new Card.Getmembers().execute();
                        } else {
                            lv.removeFooterView(pb);

                        }

                    }
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: post some code in the question

Comment: It would really help if you post some code for The Fragment with the CustomListView

Comment: that's because your code is incorrect.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. I have updated the question.